# Selecting previous and next row using sp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select previous and next row from table based on current id. I send current id to stored procedure and use this query:

```
-- previous
select top 1 id from table where id < @currentId order by id desc
-- next
select top 1 id from table where id < @currentId order by id asc
```

The problem is when I send currentId which is the last id in the table and want to select next row. Then is nothing selected. Same problem for previous row, when I send currentId which is first id in table

Is it possible to solve this in sql without additional queries?

Comment: Solve it in what way? What should be the "next" row after the last row in the table?

Comment: When currentId is last row next row would be that same row. In meantime, I created sp which returns only id, so if it return  nothing then I don't execute second procedure which select fields from table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** - just realized you always want two rows to be returned, re-working...

Updated code:

```
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE ID = (   select top 1 id 
                                from @t 
                                where id < 
                                    case 
                                        when exists (select id from @t where id < @ID) 
                                        then @ID 
                                        else (@ID + 1) 
                                    end 
                                order by id desc
                            )

UNION

SELECT * FROM @t WHERE ID = (   select top 1 id 
                                from @t 
                                where id > 
                                    case 
                                        when exists (select id from @t where id > @ID) 
                                        then @ID 
                                        else (@ID - 1) 
                                    end 
                                order by id
                            )
```

**Original Post below, before I realized what exactly you wanted**

You were really close, you needed the `UNION` operator and one small syntax change to your query.

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ID = (select top 1 id from @t where id < @ID order by id desc)
UNION
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ID = (select top 1 id from @t where id > @ID order by id)
```

This will return 1 row when the ID you pass it is the first row or last row, 2 rows otherwise.

Test code:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    Id int identity,
    Col varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES('column one')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('column two')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('column three')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('column four')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('column five')

DELETE FROM @t WHERE ID = 3

DECLARE @Id int
SET @Id = 3 -- Change this to other values to further test

SELECT * FROM @t WHERE ID = (select top 1 id from @t where id < @ID order by id desc)
UNION
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE ID = (select top 1 id from @t where id > @ID order by id)
```

Comment: It seems unsafe to assume that ids are all consecutive. This would not work if any rows had ever been deleted.

Comment: @hatchet - I noticed that just after I posted... check the updated code, I have tested by adding a DELETE command to my test code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested `top`. Example for your "next row" case.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   (SELECT TOP 2 *
        FROM   YourTable
        WHERE  id >= @currentId
        ORDER  BY id) T
ORDER  BY id DESC
```

and for the "previous row"

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   (SELECT TOP 2 *
        FROM   YourTable
        WHERE  id <= @currentId
        ORDER  BY id DESC) T
ORDER  BY id ASC
```